# Check directory permissions whether the user can create files in or not

Tags: bash, editor, ksh, vi

I need to show for a folder (lab_3il) and its 4 subfolders (aa bb cc dd) whether the user has write permissions or not and output it in 2 files

```
  -dir_with_write_perm.rep
  -dir_without_write_perm.rep
```

The folder should be passed as an argument (ex. exe_3il.ksh lab_3il)
And also create a log file.

I've tried with the while getopts but it didn't work.

```
export LOG=storage_lab3il.log
>$LOG
while getopts ":aa:bb:cc:dd:" opt; do
case $opt in
aa)a="$OPTARG" ;;
bb)b="$OPTARG" ;;
cc)c="$OPTARG" ;;
dd)d="$OPTARG" ;;
\?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" | tee -a $LOG
esac
done
echo "Subfolder: $1" | tee -a $LOG
# find out if folder has write permission or not
[ -w $1 ] && W="Write = yes" || W="Write = No"
echo "$W" | tee -a $LOG
echo  "Subfolder: $2" | tee -a $LOG
[ -w $2 ] && W="Write = yes" || W="Write = No"
echo "$W" | tee -a $LOG
echo "Subfolder: $3" | tee -a $LOG
[ -w $3 ] && W="Write = yes" || W="Write = No"
echo "$W" | tee -a $LOG
echo "Subfolder: $4" | tee -a $LOG
[ -w $4 ] && W="Write = yes" || W="Write = No"
echo "$W" | tee -a $LOG
```

I expect to output whether a file can be written in a given subfolder or not (by the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some implementation without `getopts` that may not be xactly what you want but can show you off how you could achieve similar result:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Logfile
LOG=storage_lab3il.log

# Main folder
folder=./lab_3il

# Erase log file
true >"$LOG"

# The permission files to write to depending if writable
permfile_writable="$folder/-dir_with_write_perm.rep"
permfile_readonly="$folder/-dir_without_write_perm.rep"

# Delete the permission files
rm -f -- "$permfile_writable" "$permfile_readonly" || true

# While there is a subfolder argument
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  subfolder="$1" && shift # pull subfolder argument

  # Continue to next if subfolder is not a directory
  [ ! -d "$folder/$subfolder" ] && continue

  # Test if sub-folder argument is writable
  if [ -w "$folder/$subfolder" ]; then
    permfile="$permfile_writable"
    perm=yes
  else
    permfile="$permfile_readonly"
    perm=no
  fi

  # Append the sub-folder name
  # in its corresponding permission file
  echo "$subfolder" >>"$permfile"

  # Log: Writable = yes|no sub-folder argument name
  printf 'Writable = %s: %s\n' "$perm" "$subfolder" >>"$LOG"
done
```

Comment: This gave me a good idea! Thanks! However, now I need to be able to use the script to check the root, home or any other directory for the rights + list its contents. How do I make it accessible by all other directories?